# contenteditable div: capture input event, ignore paste event

Tags: javascript, html, events, contenteditable

I'm trying to build a shortcut expander, so when a user types a certain sequence of characters, it's replaced with some longer sentence.

I'm currently using 'input' event to capture contenteditable changes. The issue is, pasting also triggers the 'input' event. I only want the event to fire when user types in a character. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use a [`KeyboardEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#interface-KeyboardEvent) event, e.g. [`keydown`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#event-type-keydown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to detect a keyboard event (keydown, keyup or keypress) instead of `oninput`, but which to choose, depends on what the handler actually will do.

If you don't want/can't use keyboard detection, there's a back-gate. It looks like `onpaste` would fire before `oninput` (Chrome, FF). Hence you could create a flag for paste, and check it in `oninput` handler. Something like this:

```
var pasted = false,
    pad = document.getElementById('pad'); // The contenteditable
pad.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
    pasted = true;
});
pad.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    if (pasted) {
        pasted = false;
        return;
    }
    console.log('keyboard, cut or drop');
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snxz0om8/1/).

Notice, that `oninput` is fired also ondrop and oncut as well as onpaste and typing in. If you don't want to handle any of these events in `oninput` handler, you've to listen all these events, and set a flag accordingly.

As a sidenote, IE doesn't fire `oninput` on contenteditables. If you want to support IEs, you need to use `onkeypdown/up`-`onpaste`-`oncut`-`ondrop` combination to achieve something similar to `oninput`.

Comment: if I use keydown event, how would I know it's a paste event?

Comment: @KevenWang  Returning early, if `CTRL` is pressed might work?